# Bessel function, integrals equality

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

How could I prove

$$
 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cos(xu)}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} \, du = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xu)}{\sqrt{u^2 - 1}} \, du
\ 
$$

?

Do I need to use Cauchy's Residue Theorem or is it possible to prove without complex analysis?

P.S. Both should be equal to $\frac{\pi}{2} J_0(x)$, but I want to prove it.

Comment: LHS is just using one of the definition $J_0(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(u\cos\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta$.  See [this question](/q/2135946/).

Comment: Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2544522/16033).